# Possible loss of precision during conversion of float number

Tags: java, decimal, floating-point-precision

I have google on how to get 2 decimal for a float number in java. Below are my codes. Finally here `float totalWeight = 0.1*levinWeight+0.8*lsmWeight;` I get the error of possible loss of precision ? I would want to first covert the string into float and then have it to be 2 decimal places.

```
float levinWeight = Float.parseFloat(dataOnlyCombine[2]);
float lsmWeight = Float.parseFloat(dataOnlyCombine[3]);
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.##");
levinWeight = Float.valueOf(df.format(levinWeight));
lsmWeight = Float.valueOf(df.format(lsmWeight));
float totalWeight = 0.1*levinWeight+0.8*lsmWeight;
```

Comment: Don't use float. Ever. Unless you have many of them and you know they can represent the numbers you have with satisfactory precision. Since you obviously do not know this, this is a good reason to use double.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are concerned about precision

- don't use `float`, it has the lowest precision of any option available.  I suggest using `double` or `BigDecimal`
- use operation which involve values which can be accurately represented.  `0.1 * x` will give you error because `0.1` cannot be represented precisely.  Using `x / 10.0` will have less error.

I would write something like this

```
double levinWeight = Double.parseDouble(dataOnlyCombine[2]);
double lsmWeight = Double.parseDouble(dataOnlyCombine[3]);
double totalWeight = (levinWeight + 8 * lsmWeight) / 10.0;
// perform rounding only at the end as appropriate.

// to round to two decimal places 
double totalWeight2 = Math.round(totalWeight * 100) / 100.0;
```

Comment: how to get the 2 decimal ?

Comment: I this correct to get the rounding for 2 decimaly at the end DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.##");
String totalWeightValue = df.format(totalWeight);

Comment: @user2711681 That will would by is both complicated and slower than using rounding.  See my updated example.

Comment: how you ensure for 2 decimals with your method just by diving 100.0 ?

Comment: @user2711681 it multiplies by 100 first, then rounds, then divides by 100.0.  This gives you accuracy to nearest multiple of 0.01

Answer (score 0):

```
float levinWeight = Float.parseFloat(dataOnlyCombine[2]);
float lsmWeight = Float.parseFloat(dataOnlyCombine[3]);
float totalWeight = 0.1*levinWeight+0.8*lsmWeight;
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.##");
String totalWeightValue = df.format(totalWeight);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to do it like that, then use BigDecimal. Those floating point classes are perfect for precision. Take a look at them:

- http://voidexception.weebly.com/java-bigdecimal---dealing-with-high-precision-calculations.html
- http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html
- http://www.javaworld.com/article/2075315/core-java/make-cents-with-bigdecimal.html

Default IEEE 746 floating points will not suit your needs. Alternatively, you could use integers and thread them factor 100. So:

- 100 is equivalent to 1.00
- 452 is equivalent to 4.52
- 1 is equivalent to 0.01